# How can I merge two lists of emails to get rid of duplicates without any programming?

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, script

Say that I have two lists of emails, that look something like

```
foo@example.com, john@doe.com, boo@boo.com

boo@boo.com, jane@bigcorp.com
```

and I need to put them together into one big list while eliminating duplicates, so it will look like

```
foo@example.com, john@doe.com, boo@boo.com, jane@bigcorp.com
```

these lists are large (50+), so doing it manually requires a lot of time.

The problem is, that I need a farily regular user to do this, so it can't involve any programming. An ideal way would be for him to just paste those lists, click once and get the resulting list.

**Are there any utilities that can do this easily? I can imagine MS Excel doing something like this, but I don't really know how to approach it.** If you have any solution not involving Excel, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: try adding them to address book of some mailing client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you have any solution not involving Excel, I'll gladly accept it.

```
$ cat list1
foo@example.com
john@doe.com
boo@boo.com

$ cat list2
boo@boo.com
jane@bigcorp.com

$ cat list1 list2 | sort -u
boo@boo.com
foo@example.com
jane@bigcorp.com
john@doe.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659) and multiple lists with a pattern of list*.csv, with a header line of "name" and an extension of .csv

```
logparser -i:csv -o:csv "Select distinct name into unique_names.csv from list*.csv"
```